# Wavelet transform wavdec returns matrix of the wrong size

Tags: matlab, wavelet, signal-analysis, transform

I have a question regarding the `wavdec`and `dwt` functions in MATLAB.

I am using `wavdec(y,3,db4)` on a size 1024 signal, which means I am trying to compute the third level `db4` transform of the size 1024 signal `y`. If I am thinking about this correctly, theoretically the returned matrix after the transform should also be of size 1024.

However, when I perform the transform, the matrix I get returned is size 1044, which is 20 samples bigger than my original matrix.

Would anyone please be able to explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

this is due to the fact that the default boundary handling is symmetric extension, which requires several coefficients more in order to achieve the perfect reconstruction. Try

`dwtmode('per')`

to use periodization to set the representation to be non-redundant. This will however be non-redundant only for input signal lengths being integer multiples of 2^J, where J is number of wavedec levels. Otherwise, very strange padding is used in every step of the wavedec.

P.S.: Sorry for the late answer :)